# Cobertura code coverage report for jenkins pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cobertura

I'm using the pipeline plugin for jenkins and I'd like to generate code coverage report for each run and display it along with the pipeline ui. Is there a plugin I can use to do that(e.g. Cobertura but it doesn't seem to be supported by pipeline)?

Comment: You should have provided more information. What programming language do you use? What build tool do you prefer?

Comment: I have python, javascript and other sorts of projects and I have been using Cobertura on freestyle projects to display code coverage reports. However after switching to pipeline I don't get the post build UI to setup Cobertura for the project.

Comment: Check if your plugin is [supported](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) by Pipeline job.

Comment: Looks like there's an issue open against the Cobertura plugin here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30700

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a way to add a pipeline step to publish your coverage report but it doesn't show under the BlueOcean interface. It will show fine in the normal UI.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        ...
    }
    post {
        always {
            junit '**/nosetests.xml'
            step([$class: 'CoberturaPublisher', autoUpdateHealth: false, autoUpdateStability: false, coberturaReportFile: '**/coverage.xml', failUnhealthy: false, failUnstable: false, maxNumberOfBuilds: 0, onlyStable: false, sourceEncoding: 'ASCII', zoomCoverageChart: false])
        }
    }
}
```

Note that one of the parameters to the Cobertura plugin is the XML that it will use ('**/coverage.xml' in the example).

If you are using python, you will want to use something like:

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-xml --cover-package=pkg1,pkg2 --with-xunit test
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you. Do you have a links to any documentation for this?

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cobertura/

Answer (score 49):

Nowadays you can also use the `cobertura` command directly in a Jenkinsfile

```
stage ("Extract test results") {
    cobertura coberturaReportFile: 'path-to/coverage.xml'
}
```

source: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30700

Comment: Worked for me and is a lot easier than the original solution. Thanks!

Comment: Both of them work, but this one is a lot easier on the eyes in the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: What version of Cobertura plugin is compatible for Jenkins 2.204.1

Comment: The full list of arguments can be found here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cobertura/

To list multiple arguments, simply place a comma after them (e.g. cobertura coberturaReportFile: 'path', sourceEncoding: 'ASCII').

The best way to see a description of what each property does is to use the Pipeline Syntax generator and select 'cobertura'.

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't explain the format for the "coverage target" arguments, so those can be found here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/cobertura-plugin/issues/111

Answer (score 7):

The answer from hwjp is correct, however there are extra parameters that you can add to the command that are not easy to find.

Once you have installed the Cobertura plugin, you can find the cobertura step options in

> Job Dashboard Page -> Pipeline Syntax -> Steps Reference

There's also a snippet generator which is really useful to get started at

> Job Dashboard Page -> Pipeline Syntax

**example command:**

```
cobertura coberturaReportFile: 'coverage.xml', enableNewApi: true, lineCoverageTargets: '80, 60, 70'
```

enableNewApi is a good one to set to true, as the new API is much prettier :D
setting coverage targets will automatically fail the job if the code coverage is too low

Answer (score -2):

Generate report using [command line](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cobertura-report.1.html) `cobertura-report` in specified directory and attach results as artifacts.

```
cobertura-report   [--datafile   file]    --destination  dir  [--format
       html|xml]  [--encoding encoding]  directory [--basedir dir]
```