# What is the Best plugin to integrate Node Js Istanbul code coverage into Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, chai, istanbul

I am working on a NodeJS project, chai framework is been used for the unit testing and istanbul is been used for the code coverage.

I wanted to integrate the istnabul code coverage into the Jenkins. I have googled regarding the same, but couldn't get much of the information regarding this integration.

What is the best way/best jenkins plugins available to integrate the istanbul code coverage into jenkins?

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://wiki.servoy.com/display/DOCS/Using+Istanbul+to+integrate+code+coverage+report+in+Jenkins

Comment: @trisquel Thanks for the Doc! I have already checked the above tutorial. Seeking for other ideas and views on integration.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [Cobertura plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cobertura/) to publish the reports in Jenkins.

I have an application with Angular and Karma for Unit Testing and the test coverage is performed with [Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/). For this application, the step to publish the tests in Jenkins with Cobertura looks like this:

```
    stage("Code Coverage") {
        steps {
            script {
                sh "npm run ng -- test --karma-config ./src/karma.conf.js --code-coverage"
            }
        }
        post {
            always {
                step([$class: 'CoberturaPublisher', coberturaReportFile: '**/coverage/MyApp/cobertura-coverage.xml'])
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used [this article on Medium](https://elisegev.medium.com/running-tests-and-creating-code-coverage-reports-for-react-nodejs-project-continuously-with-60312b6a2dd0), maybe you can find other useful information there as well.

Comment: For those of you who decide to use this plugin, an example of the newer Pipeline syntax can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53838669/3513260